# Opening a downloaded file and copying it

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open a file I demand from my user to download so I can use it so I am trying to copy it to my internal storage.

I tried using this code:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    myIntent.setType("text/*");
    myIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 100);


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri result= data.getData();
            Log.e("fag", result.getPath());

            copyFile(result);


        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.e("", "canceled");
        }
    }
    Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(a);
    }


  private void copyFile(Uri inputFile) {

    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inputFile.getPath());
        out = openFileOutput(NAME , MODE_PRIVATE);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ( in.read(buffer) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.close();
        out = null;
    }  catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
        fnfe1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But when I run this code, I got a `File Not Found Exception`. so I checked what `URI` I get from the intent and it isn't the path to the file but this path

```
 /document/primary:Download/5643_05072018-13-48.csv
```

and I don't know how to use this `URI`.
I got a simmmilar resualt using the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent.

So my question is can I use this code and the `URI` that I got to copy that file or I need to do it in an other way? and how in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

> in = new FileInputStream(inputFile.getPath());

Change to:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(inputFile);
```

And dont name that inputFile but uri.